# How to solve Magento 2.1.2 There has been an error processing your request error?

Tags: installation

I just installed Magento 2.1.2 and after login into the admin I immediately got this error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 202497054639
```

I read on many forums how to solve it but I think most of them are for Magento 1 and not 2.

How can I solve this and what information do I need to post here?

Comment: You should look in the folder `var/report/` for a file which name is that error log record number, so `var/report/202497054639`. Please update your question and add it's content.

Answer (score 7):

try this via command line

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629697/how-to-turn-on-error-messages-in-magento-2/34740378#34740378

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands in given order:

```
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento maintenance:enable
 rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/* var/di pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wasted a day turning in circles with these admin login issues - either report error like yours, or weird certificate complaints.

As mentioned, look in the report file (it is in var/reports)

I have had 2 kinds of errors

1) errors about files or streams that cannot be found or opened: make sure you clear caches, pagecaches & reindex

2) error about `open_basedir restriction in effect` linked to `/etc/pki/tls/certs`

`/home/alpinewi/m2.alpinewines.co.uk/magento2/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php(801): Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getSystemCaRootBundlePath()`

I eventually went digging on the bug tracker of Magento 2 and found something! This is all caused by composer and the version of composer that 2.1.2 is tracking along, which is an alpha

Edit you composer.json file

find the line

`"composer/composer": "@alpha"`

change to

`"composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1"`

now run

`composer update`

and you should see

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.0.6)
Downloading: 100%
- Removing composer/composer (1.0.0-beta1)
- Installing composer/composer (1.1.2)
Downloading: 100%
```

The ca-bundle is what fixes the error, I think. it was totally missing in the more recent alpha version

see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4359

Comment: I have just had the same problem on a bitnami instance which I updated to 2.1.2 and this fix worked again